# Timer causing issues on Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, timer

I want to run a method every 22 minutes on a servlet running on Tomcat. So I'm using this code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            update();
        } catch (SQLException | NamingException | InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, 22 * 60 * 1000, 22 * 60 * 1000);
```

I've got a feeling this is a terrible way to do it as I'm getting errors all the time regarding timers, and whenever I uploaded a new version of the servlet I don't think it stops the previous timer. I then get database connection warnings. If I reset everything and start fresh its fine.

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp is not bound in this Context
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:152)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at my.app.database.DatabaseManager.connect(DatabaseManager.java:44)
    at my.app.database.DatabaseManager.returnInfo(DatabaseManager.java:133)
    at my.app.genParse.Generate.updateHistory(Generate.java:89)
    at my.app.MyServer$1.run(MyServer.java:52)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

And also on re-launch with the new version:

```
SEVERE: The web application [/myApp] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Whats a better way to achieve or avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to using timer tasks has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4951059/1154145). Using the `ScheduledThreadpoolExecutor` class **MAY** help with the problem of having multiple threads still running when you upload a new version however I cannot say for sure that it will. This class is also preferred over the `Timer` class for various reasons discussed in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'm using that now and it seems to be running better.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldnt really use a `Timer` within a container - `Timer` spawn/reuse a thread thats managed outside of the container and this can cause problems.

Note too that as `Timer` uses a single thread if one instance of it takes too long the others accuracy can suffer.

Finally, if a `Timer` throws an unchecked exception the `Timer` thread is terminated.

For these (and other) reasons it has largely fallen out of favour - ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor is a better choice.

Again though, user managed threads within a container can be tricky. JSR-236 (Concurrency Utilities for the Java EE platform) will provide a mechanism to do so in the future, but for now its best avoided.

You can try schedule repeatable tasks via cron perhaps that could in turn call a dedicated servlet (or similar) on a regular basis

Answer (score 0):

Use a ServletContextListener to start and stop your Timer when the web application starts and stops.